# How do I emulate Play media key on a laptop with no media keys on GNU/Linux?

Tags: xorg, xserver

I have a laptop with no media keys. As I use a lot videos in background controlled by KDE Plasma browser integration (which controls the playback in the browser or whichever other program that reproduces media) I need to do sth about it.
The following script remaps the Ins key to the desired function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in this [script](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1906939), you can replace Insert default behaviour for the one desired by just:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
echo "xmodmap .Xmodmap" > ~.xinitrc
sed -i "s/keycode 118 =/keycode 118 = XF86AudioPlay/" .Xmodmap
```